# git : restrict access to specific folder for some users in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've been struggling with this a lot.

We use bitbucket to store our site files and I was the only user so far .

Recently we have added another user to our bitbucket  and here is our files structure :

```
    master branch :

     api
     core
     assets
     mvc
```

Now this new user can clone the whole repo and change whatever he wants and maybe misuse some of our private codes .

I just want to give him access to **api** folder so he can clone only that folder , changes whatever he want and commit and push ...

He will use linux ubunto and we just want to give him the api folder

is it possible ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think the best way of doing this is to create a new bitbucket account , and in that , you have to just put your **api** folder , and then invite that new user here

This way he can only clone that specific folder and commit and so on ...

Comment: I disagree. New account is far from optimal. I suggest doing what i told You in comment to @Amber answer and just create bitbucket groups. There You can set persmissions.

Comment: I concur @Jarema, since GIT doesn't get that granular (shame, but I get it), you may need to look at moving your "api" into another Repository, and then in your main Repository add the "api" directory as a SubModule.  I think there's another improved Tree structure or something in the later GIT versions, but the SubModule  should give you what you want, and also allows you to control which version in the "api" repository you want.

Answer (score 3):

No. Bitbucket (and Git in general, without some form of custom pre-receive hook on a server you control) treats the entire repository as one transactional object - if you can modify any of it, you can modify all of it.

Comment: So there is no way ? 
10000 google's worker , all has access to the whole repository ? :(

Comment: Amber is right. 

You have to split Your app/content into modules that are separate git repositories.

You can also not allow him to push, and force him to use pull requests. Then You can control what he is doing. EDIT: so there are lot of possibilities, but thats not what Your question was about :)

Comment: @mongoer Google does not use Git for its primary repository, and does not use Bitbucket as its host for when it does use Git.